# Shiny: add upload widget after input type selection

Tags: r, file-upload, shiny

I am pretty new to shiny. 
I am working on an application and at one point it gives the option of either uploading a csv file or using text input to generate the 'csv'(it's actually a data.table internally). Depending on the selection I would like either the sidebarpanel to extend and load the upload widget (or the text input to appear in the main panel)

At the moment the upload-widget shows up right when the app is loaded.
I appreciate any help!

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tagList(
    navbarPage( id = 'mynavlist', "My App",
      tabPanel("Create Boolean Gates",
           sidebarPanel(
             radioButtons("radio", label = p("Choose one option"),
                          choices = list("Upload Template" = 1, "Create Template" = 2), 
                          selected = 1),
             tags$hr(),

             ####only when selection is 'Upload Template'
             uiOutput("templ_upload"),
             tags$hr()

           ),
           mainPanel(
             #####only when upload was selected and after uploading the csv file
             tableOutput(outputId = 'table'),

             ####only when selection is 'Create Template'
             uiOutput("templ_create")
           )
  )
))))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  #### display upload widget if 'upload template' is chosen
  output$templ_upload <- renderUI({
    fileInput(inputId = 'templ_file', label = 'Choose a Template in csv 
       format')
    tags$hr()
    checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE)
    radioButtons('sep', 'Separator', 
    c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t'))
  })

  ####show the data after upload in mainpanel
  output$table <- renderTable({
    if (is.null(input$table)){
      h5("You have not uploaded a valid file")
    }else{
      template_csv <- fread(input$table$datapath, header=input$header, 
      sep=input$sep,quote=input$quote, check.names = FALSE)
      return(template_csv)
  }
 })

 ####to be finished
 #  output$templ_create <- renderUI({
 #  })
 })
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `conditionalPanel()` could be used, but I think in this case it is easier to
specify these conditions in the `renderUI()`:

(Don´t forget to use a `tagList()` if you want to pass multiple UI elements from the `renderUI()`)

```
  output$templ_upload <- renderUI({
    if(input$radio == 1){
      tagList(
        fileInput(inputId = 'templ_file', label = 'Choose a Template in csv 
                  format'),
        tags$hr(),
        checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
        radioButtons('sep', 'Separator', 
                     c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t'))
      )
    }
  })

  output$templ_create <- renderUI({
    if(input$radio == 2){
      textInput("table", "Table", "Sample text")  
    }
  })
```

Comment: under which conditions would a conditionalPanel() be more appropriate?

Comment: for more complex examples including conditional outputs,..but its mainly preference i would say,...